# LibreOffice python macro gives error while same command from python console works fine

Tags: python, bluetooth, arduino, libreoffice-calc

We are trying to write a string from a cell in a LO Calc sheet to Blue Tooth serial.

The BT connection works.
After using: "sudo rfcomm bind 7  1"
we can send strings using cutecom.

From the python command line this also works:

```
f1 = open("/dev/rfcomm7", "a")
f1.write("noot")
f1.flush()
f1.close()
```

"noot" is received fine by the HC-05 BT unit on the arduino and shown on the display.

However running the below macro from LibreOffice Calc raises the an error:

> com.sun.star.uno.RuntimeExceptionError during invoking function 
>   writetofile in module
>   file:///home/###/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python/writeToSer.py 
>   (: [Errno 29] Illegal seek 
>   /home/###/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python/writeToSer.py:17 
>   in function writetofile() [f = open("/dev/rfcomm7", "a")] 
>   /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/pythonscript.py:870 in function invoke() 
>   [ret = self.func( *args )] )

Macro in Calc:

```
import uno

def writetofile(*args):
    oDoc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    oSheet = oDoc.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
    oCell1 = oSheet.getCellByPosition(2, 80)
    shNumber = oCell1.String

    f2 = open("/home/###/pythonoefeningen/test.txt", "a")  
    f2.write(shNumber)
    f2.write("\n")
    f2.flush()
    f2.close()

    f = open("/dev/rfcomm7", "a")
    f.write("piet")  # shNumber)
    f.flush()
    f.close()
```

The f2 part was added to confirm the upper part fetching the value from the spreadsheet works and the output to a file works. (it does).
The error occurs on the line: f = open("/dev/rfcomm7", "a")

Who can explain the difference in behavior between the command line and the macro. And of course suggest a solution.

Os: linux mint 18

Cheers,

Comment: The primary difference is that the python process gets run inside the LO process, as explained at http://www.openoffice.org/udk/python/python-bridge.html#modes.  That may be affecting file permissions.  Beyond that, I have plenty of experience with LO python but none with Arduino.  To get better answers, add tags for Arduino / Blue Tooth serial.

Comment: Hi Jim K.  I figured it could be permission related. But i changed the permissions of /dev/rfcomm7 so all can read and write (766). But to no avail.